# Test local socket, but get "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: java, sockets

```
package NIO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HttpServer01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8801);
        while(true) {
            try{
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                service(socket);
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void service(Socket socket) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            printWriter.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            printWriter.println("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
            printWriter.println();
            printWriter.write("hello,nio");
            printWriter.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

after starting the server, `curl http://localhost:8801`
get

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
hello,nio%
```

Why there is a failure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You closed the socket without reading the request. This causes a reset. This is not an adequate HTTP server, and it is never going to be. Use the one provided with Java. NB There is no 'NIO' here.